# How can I store huge arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I store huge constant arrays in swift without the compiler lagging? I have made 4 arrays with about a hundred items each, and my compiler takes 2 minutes to compile. Any help would be appriceated.

**Edit**: I do not want to use core data.

Comment: You can't expect O(1) here, now can you?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by O(1)

Comment: Store the array as a JSON or PLIST file.

Comment: It was a joke :) Because it's code, and it requires time to compile. You can, as others suggested, store it in a file and load from there on runtime.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help

Comment: Did you give the arrays an explicit type? Forcing Swift to infer the type of large literal arrays will really increase compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQLite database or you can store in text file.

Comment: DB for static data, sound like a major over kill. A file is the right way to go here.

Comment: I am considering using a JSON file

Comment: Well, any file is good. Even a plist file. It's just silly to paste data into code. Not only it slows the compilation put it can break the data structure at runtime, if the data is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are initialising the array in the same line as declaration, it will slow down the compiler. The easiest way around it is to declare your array and then add objects to it. Something along the lines of

```
var arr = Array<String>()
arr.append("First Entry")
arr.append("Second Entry")
arr.append("Third Entry")
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think using a external file such as a JSON file is better!

Comment: It certainly is. But then again, you will have to parse it and store it somewhere anyway. Either way, the point is to not add values to the array at the time of declaration. I learned it the hard way